# How to center imageButons in LinearLayout and set textView below them?

Tags: android, android-layout

How to center these three circular image and set textView below them?

Above and below linearLayout are horizontal lines and other code is in child RelativeLayout of ScrollView layout.

If there is need for whole xml file, tell me.

[image: Layout]

**Here is xml code:**

```
<LinearLayout 
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
            android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/view" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/Button1"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"                    
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:scaleType="fitStart"
            android:background="@drawable/circle"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_horor_filmovi_ikonica" />

        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/ime1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/Button1"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Button1"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/Button1"
            android:text="Ime"/>

        <ImageButton 
            android:id="@+id/Button2"
            android:background="@drawable/circle"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_horor_filmovi_ikonica"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"   
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"            
            android:scaleType="fitStart"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"/>

        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/ime2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/Button2"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Button2"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/Button2"
            android:text="Ime"/>

        <ImageButton 
            android:id="@+id/Button3"
            android:background="@drawable/circle"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_horor_filmovi_ikonica"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"        
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"       
            android:scaleType="fitStart"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"/>

        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/ime3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/Button3"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Button3"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/Button3"
            android:text="Ime"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing a mistake by using Relative Layout attribute into a Linear Layout.
For example layout_below, layout_alignLeft, layout_alignRight.
To achieve what you want to do, the easiest way is to use 2 Linear Layout into the Relative Layout Root like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayoutButton"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/Button1"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/circle"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_horor_filmovi_ikonica" />


    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/Button2"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/circle"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_horor_filmovi_ikonica" />


    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/Button3"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/circle"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_horor_filmovi_ikonica" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayoutTextview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayoutButton"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ime1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Ime" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ime2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Ime" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ime3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Ime" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Edit: Change scaleType from fitStart to fitCenter.

There is also another solution which have the advantage to keep the button size is to use nested Linear Layout :

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayoutButton"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="3">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/Button1"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:background="@drawable/circle"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_horor_filmovi_ikonica"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ime1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="Ime" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/Button2"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:background="@drawable/circle"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_horor_filmovi_ikonica"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ime2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="Ime" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/Button3"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:background="@drawable/circle"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_horor_filmovi_ikonica"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ime3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="Ime" />
    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Okay. I have done that and get TextViews below, but still circles are next each other but at the start, not in center.

Comment: Try with the scaleType="fitCenter" instead of "fitStart".

Comment: Nope, still they are at the beginning.

Comment: Okay, i have successed. I have put this two lines of code in parent LinearLayout of three imageButtons - android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
             android:layout_alignParentRight="true"

Answer (score 1):

1) use a nest LinearLayout with Vertical orientation to contain your image and text and add it to the outsider linearlayout.
2) set the gravity of the outsider linearlayout to center should achieve what you want..

i didnot test it. please let me know if not work or i am not clear.

Answer (score 0):

You should change your "Android:width = warp_content" of  root LinearLayout (in other word the parent LinearLayout of the two LinearLayout) to "Android:width = match_parent". Beacuse if you want your image button to be put in the center, Their parent's view's size must be the whole screen.